# Run coded ui test with mstest on partner machine

Tags: visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I need to run some Coded UI test on a partner machine on which is installed Visual Studio Professional.

Is there any "standalone" packages with all the test-related dlls or I need to register them manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visual Studio Agent software allows tests to be run on other machines. The Agent software does not need and version of Visual Studio installed on the same machine.

The agent software includes all the DLLs etc needed to run Coded UI tests. So you should be able (but I have not verified this) to load the DLL of your Coded UI test onto the partner machine and then run the test with **mstest.exe**.

See http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=38186

Note that Visual Studio Professional does not include Coded UI test facilities, they are provided in the Premium and Ultimate versions.

Comment: I know that vs professional can't run tests, I opened this question for this reason :) btw, I'm installing Visual Studio Agents...

Comment: For other readers of this Q&A I wanted to clarify that VS Professional cannot create or run Coded UI tests.